# How to get parent of a node in Binary Tree with duplicates in Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am implementing my own Binary Tree as part of the assignment. For the remove() method, i have to make my own get_parent() method. But the trees can have duplicates as well. I looked for different solutions online, and they all implemented the get_parent by taking a value as a parameter, if i take a value, there maybe more than one nodes with the same value, so which node should i return?

The tree i have is this {-1,5,-1} (prints -1,-1,5 in in-order traversal).

This is my code for get_parent():

```
def get_parent(self,root, target): 


    if root == None: 
        return False 

    if root.val == target: 
        return root 

    # If target is present in tree, then prints the parent node
    if (self.get_parent(root.left, target) or 
        self.get_parent(root.right, target)): 
        print(root.val)
```

Now, this code runs fine but there are 2 issues:

1. I need it to return a node, not print it, when i write `return root` instead of printing it, it 
   doesn't work even with no
   duplicates.
2. It doesn't handle duplicates, since my root is -1 and
       target value is also -1, it just returns the root i.e -1 as the
       parent, while it should be returning 5.

Here's my code of left_child(), this returns the left-most child of a tree:

```
def left_child(self, node):
    """
    Returns the left-most child in a subtree.

    Args:
        node: the root node of the subtree

    Returns:
        The left-most node of the given subtree
    """
    temp = node
    while temp.left is not None:
        temp = temp.left

    return temp
```

This is the print statement which i run:

```
print(tree.get_parent(tree.root,tree.left_child(tree.root.right).val).val)
```

Basically, i want it to print 5, since 5 is the parent of the -1 (left-most child), but it just prints the -1 of the root node.

Note: If you can tell me a way of removing a node without having to find its parent, that would work too.

Comment: You don't need `get_parent` to implement `remove`.   How did you find the node to remove?  Through its parent.  Just remember it.

Comment: Well, I have to replace the node with another node, e.g if i remove the root (-1) in this case, i have to replace it with the other left-most-child of the right subtree, again -1. For that, i have to remove the right and left pointers of node with value 5 (i.e parent of left-most-child), which means i have to find the parent of the left most child.

Comment: How do you get to the leftmost child of the right subtree?  Through its parent again.  Just remember it.